# how to apply binarySearch collection for two String ararylist

Tags: java

I have String Lists called A and B. I want to search common elements between these two arraylist using binarySearch collection. how to use binarySearch for these two string arraylist so that i should able to print the common elements from the lists.

am able to apply this collection to find single element like this

```
 int index = Collections.binarySearch(arrayList,"4");

System.out.println("Element found at : " + index);
```

but how do i apply binarySearch collection to two String list to get common elements???

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a loop.

```
System.out.println("Common elements");
for(String s: list1)
    if(Collections.binarySearch(list2, s) >=0)
       System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a specific requirement to use `binarySearch`, I suggest you use `java.util.Set` for such kind of operations:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class SetTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> a = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
        Set<String> b = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("b", "c", "d"));
        a.retainAll(b);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[b, c]
```

Comment: Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c") this is for individual element...i need to store resultset values obtained by querying the database. how do i store into the hashset?

Comment: You can iterate over the result set and use `a.add(rs.get(..))`. How large is your result set? Are you sure you need to do this client side? SQL's `INTERSECT` might be the better choice here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)#INTERSECT_operator

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();


List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.sort(b);

for (String str : a)
{
    index = Collections.binarySearch(b, str);
    if (index > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Duplicate Item " + str + " found at index " + index);
    }
}
```

Comment: by using the `get(int index)` method.

Comment: @user1193904: If you notice, my print statement prints the duplicate item as well, together with the location.

Comment: i sorted both the list. in the list a common element located at the index 2, in the list b it is located at the index 1. but its printing the values -4. and its not printing the common element.